# @EJB returns null

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, ejb-3.1

I'm new to JBoss and to J2EE.  I'm attempting to contact a Singleton Bean with a Session bean.  Long term, I want to cache some information in the Singleton bean, and if its not available, lookup the relevant information in a database. But first, I'm creating the simplest use case possible.

However, when I run this simple use-case (get an application counter) in Eclipse, I'm getting a null reference to the EJB, and I'm not sure where to turn next.

I'm running Eclipse Keplar, JDK1.7, JBoss AS 7.1, EJB 3.1

Here is the jsp file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<jsp:useBean id="counter" class="com.bender.counter.Counter" scope="session"/>
<%-- <jsp:useBean id="counterBean" class="com.bender.counterbean.CounterBean" scope="application"/> --%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Test Counter</title>
</head>

<body>
Hit Counter( <%=counter.getHitCount() %> )<br/>
<%-- Hit CounterBean( <%=counterBean.getHits() %> )<br/> --%>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the first session bean

```
package com.bender.counter;

import com.bender.counterbean.CounterBean;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

@SessionScoped
public class Counter {
    @EJB 
    CounterBean counterBean;

    private int hitCount;

    public Counter() {
        this.hitCount = 0;
    }

    public int getHitCount() {
        if (counterBean == null) {
            System.out.println("Failure");
            hitCount = -1;
        } else {
            hitCount = counterBean.getHits();
        }
        return hitCount;
    }

    public void setHitCount(int newHits) {
        this.hitCount = newHits;
    }
}
```

Here is the Singleton Bean

```
package com.bender.counterbean;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class CounterBean {
    private int hits = 1;

    public CounterBean() {
        super();
        System.out.println("In constructor of CounterBean.");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.format("In post Construct of CounterBean, hits( %d )%n", this.hits);
    }

    // Increment and return the number of hits
    public int getHits() {
        return hits++;
    }
}
```

Here is the output from the server.log.  Note that the counterbean appears to register with jndi.  Note also the commented out  in the jsp.  This was an attempt to contact the CounterBean from the jsp.  That attempt was successful, so I think the CounterBean is successfully running in the server.

```
17:07:50,427 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-12) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Counter.war"
17:07:50,443 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-15) JNDI bindings for session bean named CounterBean in deployment unit deployment "Counter.war" are as follows:

    java:global/Counter/CounterBean!com.bender.counterbean.CounterBean
    java:app/Counter/CounterBean!com.bender.counterbean.CounterBean
    java:module/CounterBean!com.bender.counterbean.CounterBean
    java:global/Counter/CounterBean
    java:app/Counter/CounterBean
    java:module/CounterBean

17:07:50,458 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-8) In constructor of CounterBean.

17:07:50,458 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-8) In post Construct of CounterBean, hits( 1 )

17:07:50,474 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /Counter
17:07:50,489 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-threads - 83) JBAS018559: Deployed "Counter.war"
17:07:55,185 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Failure
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue if I lookup the bean using the Initial Context to get the JNDI name.  So, I must have the default JNDI not setup correctly for my jboss instance?

Comment: private CounterBean counterBean;
 {
  try {
   counterBean = (CounterBean) new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/Counter/CounterBean");
  } catch (NamingException e) { 
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injection only works, if the DI container (in JBoss it is weld) knows about the object. This normally happens because the container itself creates the instance. You may also pass an existing object to the container an let it inject all dependencies.

It looks like CDI injection into JSP pages does not work in JBoss AS 7:

- https://community.jboss.org/thread/195487?start=0&tstart=0
- https://community.jboss.org/thread/176930?start=0&tstart=0

Maybe you take a look at alternatives to JSP:

- JSF: [Short JSF tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAB&url=http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/&ei=uutXUt6pCY6R0QWU9YDYCg&usg=AFQjCNGTyD9ZEKBPzHSDZmW39iSEp6EViw&bvm=bv.53899372,d.d2k)
- Servlets: [Short CDI injection tutorial for Servlets](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?cat=22)

If you cannot switch to another technology, then you might have to do the injection yourself. Use the following method to let the CDI container performa all injections for the given object:

```
public static <T> void programmaticInjection(Class<T> clazz, T injectionObject) throws NamingException {
    InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
    Object lookup = initialContext.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
    BeanManager beanManager = (BeanManager) lookup;
    AnnotatedType<T> annotatedType = beanManager.createAnnotatedType(clazz);
    InjectionTarget<T> injectionTarget = beanManager.createInjectionTarget(annotatedType);
    CreationalContext<T> creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null);
    injectionTarget.inject(injectionObject, creationalContext);
    creationalContext.release();
}
```

Then call this method from your JSP:

```
<h3>Inject Test</h3>
          <%
                    MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
                    myBean.programmaticInjection(MyBean.class, myBean);
                    // now call a method on myBean that invokes the injected EJB
          %>
</body>
</html>
```

`MyBean` is here a simple JSF bean, similar to yours:

```
@Named("myBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyBean.class);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private long taskId;
    @EJB
    private MyEjb myEjb;
```

After calling `programmaticInjection()` the @EJB annotated object will be injected.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.  However, I think you misunderstood my question.  The issue was not in the JSP page, I was able to access both beans without issue.  The issue was in the session bean getting a reference (via @EJB) to the Singleton bean.  Again, thanks for your response, it gives some great ideas on access to the context to make changes.

Comment: No, I did not misunderstood your question. The @EJB annotation is evaluated by the CDI container only if it a) constructs the instance or b) you let it inject by the method given above. It is null because no injection happens, because the implementation of the jsp:useBean tag does not know about the CDI container and therefore cannot ask it to construct the instance or let it do the injections. You solution of looking up the bean from JNDI works, but this is excatly the same what the JBoss container does, when he sees an EJB annotation.

Comment: Please accept my apologies, now I understand your answer much better.  Thank you for taking the to clarify.  Since this is sample code and I'm only in the learning phase, I'll switch over to JSF to get CDI working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem by adding a JNDI lookup.  I must have something not setup correctly within my JBoss AS 7.1 instance so that one bean can use the (default) JNDI, while the JSP pages have (full) JNDI access.  Here is the updated (and cleaned up) code.

JSP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<jsp:useBean id="counter" class="com.bender.counter.Counter" scope="session"/>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Test Counter</title>
</head>

<body>
Hit Counter( <%=counter.getHitCount() %> )<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Session Bean (note that the @EJB is commented out)
    package com.bender.counter;

```
import com.bender.counterbean.CounterBean;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

@SessionScoped
public class Counter {
//    @EJB
    private CounterBean counterBean;
    {
        try {
            counterBean = (CounterBean) new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/Counter/CounterBean");
        } catch (NamingException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private int hitCount;

    public Counter() {
        this.hitCount = 0;
    }

    public int getHitCount() {
        if (counterBean == null) {
            System.out.println("Failure");
            hitCount = -1;
        } else {
            hitCount = counterBean.getHits();
        }
        return hitCount;
    }

    public void setHitCount(int newHits) {
        this.hitCount = newHits;
    }
}
```

And the Singleton Bean

```
package com.bender.counterbean;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;


@Startup
@Singleton
public class CounterBean {
    private int hits = 1;

    public CounterBean() {
        super();
        System.out.println("In constructor of CounterBean.");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.format("In post Construct of CounterBean, hits( %d )%n", this.hits);
    }

    // Increment and return the number of hits
    public int getHits() {
        return hits++;
    }
}
```

And here is the JBoss Console Output

```
16:21:55,740 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-12) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Counter.war"
16:21:55,888 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean named CounterBean in deployment unit deployment "Counter.war" are as follows:

    java:global/Counter/CounterBean!com.bender.counterbean.CounterBean
    java:app/Counter/CounterBean!com.bender.counterbean.CounterBean
    java:module/CounterBean!com.bender.counterbean.CounterBean
    java:global/Counter/CounterBean
    java:app/Counter/CounterBean
    java:module/CounterBean

16:21:56,033 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) In constructor of CounterBean.

16:21:56,033 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) In post Construct of CounterBean, hits( 1 )

16:21:56,088 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /Counter
16:21:56,093 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started in 2001ms - Started 185 of 258 services (72 services are passive or on-demand)
16:21:56,176 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "Counter.war"
16:22:11,455 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) In constructor of CounterBean.
```